# MYSQL Generate timestamp from Year and Month

Tags: mysql, timestamp, date

I have a mysql table with two columns - one containing a year in YYYY format, and another containing a month in full name format ' January', 'May', 'September' etc.

I need to extract each row from the table in date order, and so need to convert/combine these two values into UNIX timestamp format.

Does anyone have any clues how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
order by str_to_date(CONCAT_WS('-', YearCol, MonthCol), '%Y-%M-01')
```